# Json Transformation using Undercore js

Tags: javascript, json, api, underscore.js

Below is the response I am receiving

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      "appointment": "string",
      "archived": true,
      "clinical_note_sections": [
        {
          "clinical_note_template": 0,
          "name": "string",
          "values": [
            {
              "clinical_note_field": 0,
              "id": 0,
              "value": "string"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "patient": "string"
    }
  ],
  "next": "string",
  "previous": "string"
}
```

I want to include appointment and patient in the values Array[ ]. So the end result should look like that

```json
{
  "data": [
    {
      /* ... */
      "values": [
        {
          "clinical_note_field": 0,
          "id": 0,
          "value": "string",
          "appointment": "string",
          "patient": "string"
        }
      ]
      /* ... */
    }
  ],
  "next": "string",
  "previous": "string"
}
```

Any example of using underscore js that can do this type of transformation?

Answer (score 1):

If plain JS suits you, then...

```js
const newProps = { "appointment": "string", "patient": "string" }
data.forEach(d => d.clinical_note_sections.forEach(cns => cns.values.forEach(v => Object.assign(v,newProps))))
```

Comment: I am able to get the desire output in Plain JS but trying to achieve it using underscore js

Comment: Ah ok, perfect.

Comment: How did you get the desired result using plain JS, @AsadRauf?